# DOS: find a string, if found then run another script

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to find  a string in a file using DOS:

For example

> find "string" status.txt

And when it is found, I want to run a batch file.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Does `find` return different `errorlevel` values depending on whether the string is found? If so, there's your solution right there.

Comment: Do you really mean MS-DOS or do you mean the cmd.exe batch interpreter on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls
MD %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\
CLS
TIMEOUT /T 1 >NUL
CLS
systeminfo >%homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\info.txt
cls
timeout /t 3 >nul
cls
find "x64-based PC" %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\info.txt >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto 32bitsok
goto 64bitsok
cls

:commandlineerror
cls
echo error, command failed or you not are using windows OS.
pause >nul
cls
exit

:64bitsok
cls
echo done, system of 64 bits
pause >nul
cls
del /q /f %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\info.txt >nul
cls
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
RD %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\ >nul
cls
exit

:32bitsok
cls
echo done, system of 32 bits
pause >nul
cls
del /q /f %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\info.txt >nul
cls
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
RD %homedrive%\TEMPBBDVD\ >nul
cls
exit
```

Answer (score 29):

It's been awhile since I've done anything with batch files but I think that the following works:

```
find /c "string" file
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo found
goto done
:notfound
echo notfound
goto done
:done
```

This is really a proof of concept; clean up as it suits your needs. The key is that `find` returns an `errorlevel` of `1` if `string` is not in `file`. We branch to `notfound` in this case otherwise we handle the `found` case.

Comment: It's better to use `if errorlevel 1`. It has slightly different semantics, though, but is overall more robust.

Answer (score 10):

```
C:\test>find /c "string" file | find ": 0" 1>nul && echo "execute command here"
```

Comment: This was my initial approach but I don't like relying on the output of `find` henceforth containing `: 0`. I couldn't find (pun intended) documentation supporting this and think the `errorlevel` approach might be more future proof.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the /c switch. Otherwise 'find' does not report count (": 0")

Answer (score 7):

We have two commands,  first is "condition_command", second is  "result_command".
If we need run "result_command" when "condition_command" is successful (errorlevel=0):

```
condition_command && result_command
```

If we need run "result_command" when "condition_command" is fail:

```
condition_command || result_command
```

Therefore for run "some_command" in case when we have "string" in the file "status.txt":

```
find "string" status.txt 1>nul && some_command
```

in case when we have not "string" in the file "status.txt":

```
find "string" status.txt 1>nul || some_command
```

Answer (score 6):

As the answer is marked correct then it's a Windows Dos prompt script and this will work too:

```
find "string" status.txt >nul && call "my batch file.bat"
```

Comment: access denied on windows

Comment: @Jack That's a problem with your permissions on the files or folder you are using.

Answer (score -1):

That's more straightforward:

```
find /c "string" file
if %errorlevel% not equ 1 goto something
```

Comment: gives error `not was unexpected at this time.`