# Deleting part of a file's name

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, mp3

I'm trying to remove a certain part of a mp3's name.
So if mp3 is "X (2015)" I want it to recognize the "(2" and delete the rest of the name so I can delete it for every year.

Comment: Try this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875241/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875241/3710490)

Comment: Give a clear example please.

Comment: file1 = "X (2015)" --> file 1 = "X" ; file2 = "Y (2012) --> file2 = "Y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curiously enough, the most difficult part of this problem is to eliminate *the space* before the left parenthesis. The Batch file below just eliminate the last character of the new name; if the number of spaces before the left paren may be variable, then a different approach must be used.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *(2*.mp3') do (
   for /F "delims=(" %%b in ("%%a") do set "name=%%b"
   ECHO ren "%%a" "!name:~0,-1!.mp3"
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> dir /B *.mp3
X (2015).mp3
Y (2012).mp3

C:\> test.bat
ren "X (2015).mp3" "X.mp3"
ren "Y (2012).mp3" "Y.mp3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*(*.mp3" '
  ) DO (FOR /f "tokens=1delims=(" %%g IN ("%%a") DO ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%~g%%~xa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The directory list in `/b` basic form is processed and the filenames assigned to `%%a`. The filemask selects only those filenames that contain `(`

`%%a` is then partitioned into the part-before and the part after the first `(` and the part before assigned to `%%g`

It's then a matter of stringing the command together.